# Facebook says I have 4200 friends... download account and get 3700 names

Tags: facebook

Facebook says I have 4200 friends but when I download my account I get only 3700 names...  How do I find these 500 invisible friends to unfriend them?

These are not the ghost accounts one finds when viewing friends list from profile... Ghost accounts are the deactivated ones with no picture and no friends where when you unfriend them an add friend button does not appear.

Answer (score 1):

Probably those 500 accounts are deactivated. To confirm it you have to check one by one.

Go to your Friends section in your Profile and look for those profiles which doesn't have profile pictures, click on the name and it will show a pop-up if it is deactivated. In the pop-up message there will an option to unfriend.

Comment: I have done all that... These 500 don't show up anywhere...

Comment: Then report about it to Facebook.